# Passing in unspecialized class as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class that looks like this:

```
template <typename T> struct myclass;
template <typename T> struct myclass {
  T value;
  vector< unique_ptr<myclass<T>> > children;
};
```

This works great, but what I'd really like is to be able to specify vector as a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, typename Container> struct myclass;
template <typename T, typename Container> struct myclass {
  T value;
  Container< unique_ptr<myclass<T>> > children;
}

myclass<int, vector> x;
```

I understand that this doesn't work, how do I do something like it where Container can be any vector-like class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, those are called [template-templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter). It's a mouthful of a name, but the syntax is roughly what you want it to be.

```
template <typename T, template <typename> typename Container>
struct MyClass {
  T value;
  Container< unique_ptr<MyClass<T, Container>> > children;
}

MyClass<int, std::vector> x;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Sometimes it's just a matter of finding the right search keyword on google!

Comment: That's exactly what sites like this are for. Glad I could be of help. Good luck! :)